# edittext text default value appear on empty and clear the default value when write on it

Tags: android

In android edit-text have default value username but when some write on it the default value username is disappear and the write continue if the edit text again empty the text appear username on it again. How can I do it?

Comment: `android:hint="Type your text here"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the **Default text** in the hint section of your `EditText` in xml file

```
    <EditText
        . . .
        android:hint="Your default text here" 
    />
```